# Issues when creating test using vitest

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, prisma, zod

I created a next.js app using typescript, prisma and trpc using, So far i have integrated auth0 so users can log in. **I am using the new next.js app router**

I'm experiencing errors when i run tests using vitest. The test i created is trying to check if "Welcome!" displays on my component as follows:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Welcome from "../app/page";
import { describe, test, expect, it } from "vitest";

test("1 + 1", () => {
  expect(1 + 1).toEqual(2);
});

 describe("Welcome", () => {
   test("welcome component displays", () => {
     render(<Welcome />);
     const message = screen.getByText("Hello");
     expect(message).toBeVisible();
   });
});
```

when i run the test i get the following error:

```
Error: ❌ Attempted to access a server-side environment variable on the client
 ❯ onInvalidAccess node_modules/@t3-oss/core/index.ts:223:13
 ❯ Object.get node_modules/@t3-oss/core/index.ts:246:16
 ❯ src/server/db.ts:13:11
     11|   new PrismaClient({
     12|     log:
     13|       env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? ["query", "error", "warn"] : ["error"],
       |           ^
     14|   });
     15| 
 ❯ src/server/auth.ts:5:31
```

I have tried looking for places which might be trying to access server-side environment variable on the client side specifically in src/server/db.ts and src/serverauth.ts but they are in the server folder which i think are okay
I've also tried removing the respected areas but it doesn't seem to work

here are the the auth.ts and db.ts respectively:

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import {
  getServerSession,
  type DefaultSession,
  type NextAuthOptions,
} from "next-auth";
import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

import { env } from "~/env.mjs";
import { db } from "~/server/db";

/**
 * Module augmentation for `next-auth` types. Allows us to add custom properties to the `session`
 * object and keep type safety.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation
 */
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      id: string;
      // ...other properties
      // role: UserRole;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }

  // interface User {
  //   // ...other properties
  //   // role: UserRole;
  // }
}

/**
 * Options for NextAuth.js used to configure adapters, providers, callbacks, etc.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
 */
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: user.id,
      },
    }),
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "login",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

/**
 * Wrapper for `getServerSession` so that you don't need to import the `authOptions` in every file.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs
 */
export const getServerAuthSession = () => getServerSession(authOptions);
```

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

import { env } from "~/env.mjs";

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
};

export const db =
  globalForPrisma.prisma ??
  new PrismaClient({
    log:
      env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? ["query", "error", "warn"] : ["error"],
  });

if (env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalForPrisma.prisma = db;
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I'm experiencing a similar one and am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @Benji 
Sorry for the late reply-  so essentially you must mock the getServerAuthSession function in your test. This blog [here](https://medium.com/@self.muhammad/mocking-your-vitests-6d90c768982f) 
explains how you can do so.